# VSTS Where is release management?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

It looks like some changes were made to VSTS yesterday. Release definitions are no longer visible under the "Build and Release" tab. The 3 options available are Builds, Library and Task Groups.

Comment: Sounds like a security issue. Is your account privileged enough to see those areas?

Comment: I am an admin. Its been working fine for 2 years now.

Comment: i'm facing the same issue! i'm the admin

Comment: can you access to this url: `https://{youraccount}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_release` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of a global azure outage.https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/status/

Comment: Yeah I was aware of the outage but couldn't understand why a tab alone was not showing. But its seems to have come back.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Service outage, you are unable to find the release management in Build and release in VSTS.

You may monitor the [Azure Status](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/status/) Page for further updates.

Unfortunately we cannot do anything until the problem has been mitigated by Azure engineering team.