# Release not in Build&Release

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Couldn't find Release in Build and release in VSTS, is it moved to some other place today, if  yes can you please share the navigation?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178144/vsts-where-is-release-management

Comment: Could you add a related screenshot? Are you using the old navigation or the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Due to Service outage, you are unable to find the release in Build and release in VSTS.

You may monitor the [Azure Status](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/status/) Page for further updates.

Unfortunately we cannot do anything until the problem has been mitigated by Azure engineering team.